# Leakcanaray, memory leak only on some devices

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

For my already deployed app Im trying to ensure, that no memory leaks occur. Im using leakcanary in debug versions and also the android studio memory profiling tools to detect possible leaks.
So far Ive tested this on 6 different devices. 5 of them Ive directly debugged via memory profiling und could not find any leaks. Old Activities and Fragments were properly garbage collected even after multiple rotations so on. On these 5 devices, leakcanary does not show any leaks as well.

The 6th device however, showed a leakcanary notification from early on. Some fragments have leaked. Unfortunately I have not been able to run this 6th device through memory profiling since its not my smartphone. The device is a HUAWEI with Android 8. Im having another Android 8 device from XIAOMI which does not show any leaks.

Questions:

1. Do different Model/Brands/CustomRoms have different (unique / custom) garbage collection mechanisms? I thought not.
2. If not, is there an easy explanation for this behavior of leakcanary or could it be a malfunction?
3. Is it possible, that a Fragment or an Activity requires 2 or more garbage collection attempts in order to get collected? If so, could this cause the 
   strange behavior? (I think leakcanary tries to gcs once and dump memory if reference still exists)

Thank yo guys!

Comment: 1) The garbage collector will be that of Android Runtime, which does a mark/sweep process - implementation will be Android's for that API Version on the device 2) My experience of leak canary is mixed so can't offer concrete information 3) Yes, between 2 garbage collections strong references could be dereferenced, true memory leaks are when strong references can't be accessed to dereference.

Comment: 1. Different Android API version will have different GC implementation (Android >= 5.0 which use ART instead of Dalvik VM will have enhanced CMS collector).

2,3. Do you test the same behavior that your HUAWEI was test when it detect mem leaks?

Comment: @MarkKeen Thx, so is it possible that I have a memory leak on certain devices while I dont have one on others?

Comment: @nhoxbypass Thx for answering. Could you clarify your question plz, I do not understand, sry.